# Compress whole directory with rsync and upload to remote

Tags: rsync

I know I can go like:

```
rsync -zaP uploads/ myserver:/path/to/
```

If I understand right, that will compress each file in that directory and sync one by one to the server. But if it's thousands of files, then it's going to take some time. Much faster would be to compress the whole directory and upload that.

So, is there a porcelain way for me to do that with `rsync`?

### Helper function

I wrote a little bash function to compress and move move a whole directory with `rsync`. How would you simplify it or make it better?

```
function zipsync() {
    # Arguments
    local source=$1
    local target=$2

    # Get the host and path from the $target string
    IFS=':' read -a array <<< "$target"
    local host=${array[0]}
    local remote_path=${array[1]}

    # The archive file locations
    local remote_archive=${remote_path}${source}.tar.gz
    local local_archive=${source}.tar.gz

    # Colors
    cya='\033[0;36m'; gre='\033[0;32m'; rcol='\033[0m'

    echo -e "$cya Compressing files $rcol"
    tar -zcvf $local_archive $source

    echo -e "$cya Syncing files $rcol"
    rsync -avP $local_archive $target

    echo -e "$cya Extracting file in remote $remote_archive $rcol"
    ssh $host "cd ${remote_path}; tar zxvf ${remote_archive}"

    echo -e "$cya Removing the archives $rcol"
    ssh $host "rm $remote_archive"
    rm $local_archive

    echo -e "$gre All done :) $rcol"
}
```

Syntax:

```
zipsync source target
```

Example:

```
$ zipsync uploads my_server:/var/www/example.com/public_html
```

Problems with that function:

1. Can't tab complete in local machine.
2. Can't tab complete in remote server.
3. Can't specify port in the target path, this won't work: `zipsync uploads -p 5555 bob@xmpl.com:/path/` cause the `-p` is read as the second parameter.

My goal was to make a command that is really simple to use and reassembles `rsync`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> If I understand right, `rsync -zaP uploads/ myserver:/path/to/` will
>   compress each file in that directory and sync one by one to the
>   server.

This is incorrect. The `rsync` command looks at the local files, compares them to the remote files (if any), and then synchronises the *differences* to the server. If there are no matching remote files then there will be no speed increase. However, for subsequent uploads where only some of the files have been changed, the speed increase can become dramatic. The `-z` flag attempts to apply compression to the data being transferred over the link.

> But if it's thousands of files, then it's going to take some
>   time. Much faster would be to compress the whole directory and upload
>   that.
>   So, is there a porcelain way for me to do that with rsync?

Your understanding was flawed so I think this question becomes moot. The rest of your post doesn't appear to be a question so I'm not sure what answers you're expecting. Please update the question if I've got that wrong.

Comment: say the *differences* are all the files, e.g. the files do not exist at the destination, will `rsync` zip all the files *individually* and transport them one-by-one, or will it zip them *together*, and transfer them as one file (unzipping at the destination)?

Comment: @JamesOwers I think you're misunderstanding `rsync` in the same way that the OP was. My answer applies to your comment too.

Comment: I understand it's going to send *differences* not whole files, is that what you mean (in my example above it will send whole files though)? The line in your answer of interest to me is "The -z flag attempts to apply compression to the data being transferred over the link" - does it great a single zip file internally and send that, or does it zip individual changes?

Comment: @JamesOwers there is no zip involved. The data blocks are compressed (using the `zlib` library). More detail is in the man page for `rsync`.

Comment: Sorry, this is me not using the correct terminology. All I mean by 'zip' is 'compressed group of data'.

Unfortunately the man page didn't help. https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.html states for the -z option:  "rsync compresses the file data as it is sent to the destination machine, which reduces the amount of data being transmitted -- something that is useful over a slow connection". This *sounds* like exactly what I want, but I'm trying to establish for sure that this is not a 'compressed block' per change (as there will be many), but rather as few 'compressed blocks' as possible

Comment: @JamesOwers oh I see. I think. As far as I know the transmission blocks are treated by the compression layer as a continuous stream - including blocks that contain the list of files, if appropriate - so if you were to send two short identical files the second one might be compressed using the dictionary derived from the first. However, since I don't know this for sure I've asked the question over on [unix.SE] at [Is the rsync block compression dictionary reset for each file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/553111/100397).

Answer (score 8):

If you want to run this only a single time where the destination is empty then it can be faster yes.
But your function is over complicated.
You can just run:

```
 tar zcvf - /source | ssh destination.example.com "cd /destination; tar xvzf -"
```

If you want to run the sync to synchronize changes, then see the answer from roaima.

Comment: @faker Could you please clarify for what the dash `-` actually does there?

Comment: The first dash tells tar to ouput to stdout, the last dash tells tar to read from stdin